# EditText количество знаков после запятой

Tags: android, android-edittext

Нужно чтоб после запятой было разрешено ввести не более 2 знаков в EditText.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: Есть готовая [библиотека Android-NumberEditText](https://github.com/hyperax/Android-NumberEditText)

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте такой вариант

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2)});
```

код класса InputFilter

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    Pattern mPattern;
    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)